# Capture bitmap of entire software window with winapi

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to capture several software window and print them to my software. The goal is to be able to view two different software side to side even if they overlap.

```
void MyWindowFinder::drawTo(HWND hWnd){
    MyWindow* currentWindow = anchorWindow;

    HDC hdcRendering;
    HDC hdcMemRendering;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    hdcRendering = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    hdcMemRendering = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcRendering);

    int widthToRender = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this->anchorWindow->winID ; i++){
        HDC hdcCapture;
        HDC hdcMemCapture;
        HBITMAP hBitmap;
        HGDIOBJ oldCaptureBitmap;
        HGDIOBJ oldRenderingBitmap;

        RECT clientRect;
        GetClientRect(currentWindow->hwnd,&clientRect);
        int width = clientRect.right-clientRect.left;
        int height = clientRect.bottom-clientRect.top ;

        if (!(hdcCapture = GetDC (currentWindow->hwnd))){
            return;
        }

        hdcMemCapture = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcCapture);
        hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcCapture,clientRect.right-clientRect.left,clientRect.bottom-clientRect.top);

        oldCaptureBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMemCapture, hBitmap);
        BitBlt(hdcMemCapture, 0, 0, width, height, hdcCapture, 0,0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

        oldRenderingBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMemRendering, hBitmap);
        BitBlt(hdcRendering, widthToRender, 0, width, height, hdcMemCapture, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        widthToRender+= width;
        SelectObject(hdcMemRendering, oldRenderingBitmap);
        SelectObject(hdcMemCapture, oldCaptureBitmap);


        DeleteDC(hdcMemCapture);
        DeleteDC(hdcCapture);

        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        currentWindow = currentWindow->previousWindow;
    }
    DeleteDC(hdcMemRendering);
    DeleteDC(hdcRendering);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
```

This works pretty well and I can print two overlapping window side to side in my software :

[image: Side to side overlapped window]
However I'm facing a tricky problem. When I click on any element of one of my children software, they are not drawn in my software.

Do you have any idea why, and how I could solve this problem ?

Comment: It just worked by accident, relying on an implementation detail of Windows Media Player.  It uses a layered window, also why you had to use the CAPTUREBLT option.  You run out of luck when another kind of window is in the foreground that's not a layered window.  There's no real path ahead here, you'll have to ensure that whatever window you want to capture is in the foreground.  That's lots of flickering and blinking and outright failure, SetForegroundWindow() cannot be relied upon.  PrintWindow() is another way, also not 100% reliable.

Comment: Well, I do not understand your comment Hans. I tried with other software (Texmaker, chrome) and it worked the same. The windows can be hidden and the windows are still captured. I also removed the CAPTUREBLT option since it was actually unuseful, and it worked also the same.

Comment: @Al_th child windows have to be drawn on the parent window. [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) function will give you HWNDs of child windows. You have to draw them on the parent window.